# GHC error message quotes type family definition verbatim

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

The code below results in an error message that, at first glance, appears to imply that GHC doesn't understand the definition of the type family `WrapParams` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits( Nat, type (-) )
import Data.Kind( Type )

newtype Wrapped a = Wrapped a

-- |
-- E.g., `WrapParams 2 (Int -> String -> Bool)` is `Wrapped Int -> Wrapped String -> Bool`
--
type family WrapParams (n :: Nat) (f :: Type) where
  WrapParams 0 f = f
  WrapParams n (p -> f) = Wrapped p -> WrapParams (n - 1) f


-- |
-- E.g., `extendToWrappedParams @2 (+) (Wrapped 1) (wrapped 2)` is supposed to be 3.
--
class ExtendToWrappedParams (n :: Nat) (f :: Type)  where
  extendToWrappedParams :: f -> WrapParams n f

instance ExtendToWrappedParams 0 t where
  extendToWrappedParams t = t

instance (ExtendToWrappedParams (n - 1) f) => ExtendToWrappedParams n (p -> f) where
  extendToWrappedParams g = h
    where
      h (Wrapped p) = extendToWrappedParams @(n - 1) @f (g p)
```

Here's the error (using GHC 8.10.7):

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘WrapParams n (p -> f)’
              with actual type ‘Wrapped p -> WrapParams (n - 1) f’
• In the expression: h
  In an equation for ‘extendToWrappedParams’:
      extendToWrappedParams g
        = h
        where
            h (Wrapped p) = extendToWrappedParams @(n - 1) @f (g p)
  In the instance declaration for ‘ExtendToWrappedParams n (p -> f)’
```

The first two lines quote the definition of `WrapParams` verbatim, giving the impression that GHC somehow didn't understand it. Obviously, that can't be what's actually happening - so, what am I missing? Is there any way (apart from resorting to `unsafeCoerce`) to make the code above compile?

Comment: If I write `data N = Z | S N` and convert your code to use it in place of `Nat`, then it works fine. I wonder if the issue is that GHC doesn't realize `n` can't be 0 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WrapParams n (p -> f)` equals `Wrapped p -> WrapParams (n - 1) f` only when `n` is not `0`. There is no direct way to express unequality in Haskell. Usual workarounds include switching to Peano naturals, or branching off boolean comparisons (`Data.Type.Equality.==`) instead of pattern-matching on `Nat` so you can write `(n == 0) ~ 'False` as a constraint.